# I want to style my container and span

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, size, containers

i'm recently looking closely to twitter bootstrap to make my team website,
but i'm in front of a problem who block me.
So there is my body :

```
  <div class="container">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Acceuil</a></li>
                    <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                    <li><a href="membres.html">Membres</a></li>
                    <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                    <li><a href="videos.html">Vidéos</a></li>
                    <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                    <li><a href="forum.html">Forum</a></li>
                    <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                </ul>
 <div class="row">
 <div class="span9">
    Column 1
 </div>
 <div class="span3">

   Column2
 </div>
</div>
 </div></i>
```

And i want the navbar to continue the border all around my container, but i don't know how to do, i use basic version of twitter bootstrap.
If some one know how to do tell me please.
http://jsbin.com/cesorozu/1/edit and here is what i want http://puu.sh/aH4bG/27021ae1ab.jpg

Thank you
Psyko460

Comment: Please include your CSS in the question.

Comment: post a proper HTML code and if possible make a demo on jsbin. http://jsbin.com/ so anyone can guess easily what exactly you want?

Comment: What do you mean by `continue the border all around my container`?

Comment: Please post your HTML and CSS code, if possible a http://jsfiddle.net/jsfile

Comment: Oh i'm sorry, so here is the html + css http://jsbin.com/cesorozu/1/edit 
and here is what i want to do 
http://puu.sh/aH4bG/27021ae1ab.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the code and the image you shared, I think you can use another div inside the span9 and span3 divs, but you should be careful with borders, and you can set your own height:

```
.bordered{
   box-sizing:border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
   -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
   border:1px solid black;
   height:400px;
 }
```

And here is [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/zigutika/1/edit)

If you don't want your divs to be on the edge, make your span grids smaller like span8 vs span3. They won't end up to 12, so you will have the space for your divs. Then simply give margin-left to your inner divs to move them(divs with the class of ".bordered" for this example).

This is an example for this: [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/pusulicu/1/edit)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much, and if i insert a div bordered on my container this will made a line on the whole container ?
And a last question did you have a website where i can find all the definition of commands like -moz-box-webkit ?

Comment: You're welcome. Yes this will draw lines on all four lines. But if you want to draw a line just on one side, you can use broder-right, border-left etc. And finally, check out these documents for "border" and "box" properties. http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-css3-border-20021107/  and http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/ and http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/

Comment: Thank you for the website you help me a lot ! That's really nice !